# Enable logging in Mercurial bugzilla extension scripts

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, how I can enable the logging in bugzilla extension scripts? e.g. the "self.ui.note" inside the bugzilla.py.

```
    host = self.ui.config('bugzilla', 'host', 'localhost')
    user = self.ui.config('bugzilla', 'user', 'bugs')
    passwd = self.ui.config('bugzilla', 'password')
    db = self.ui.config('bugzilla', 'db', 'bugs')
    timeout = int(self.ui.config('bugzilla', 'timeout', 5))
    self.ui.note(_('connecting to %s:%s as %s, password %s\n') %***
                 (host, db, user, '*' * len(passwd)))
    self.conn = bzmysql._MySQLdb.connect(host=host,
                                               user=user, passwd=passwd,
                                               db=db,
                                               connect_timeout=timeout)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    self.longdesc_id = self.get_longdesc_id()
    self.user_ids = {}
    self.default_notify = "cd %(bzdir)s && ./processmail %(id)s %(user)s"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will do what you want since I don't have time to look in the source. But you should try one of the following command line parameters :

```
-v, --verbose
     enable additional output 

--debug
     enable debugging output
```

Comment: @user1087418 You should upvote and accept answers on your question to encourage people helping you. And since it seems you have problems with the bugzilla extension, maybe try asking on the mailing list and/or IRC chan of the project instead of here.